# How to apply rules that can be defined at runtime to streaming datasets?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Not sure the title is well suited to what I'm trying to achieve, so bear with me.

I'll start with defining my use case:

Many(say millions) IoT devices are sending data to my Spark stream. These devices are sending the current temperature level every 10 seconds. 
The owner of all of these IoT devices has the ability to define a preset rules, for example: if temperature > 50 then do something.

I'm trying to figure out if I can output how many of these devices have met this if > 50 criteria in some time period. The catch is that the rules are defined in real time and should be applied to the Spark job at real time.

How would I do that. Is Spark the right tool for the job?

Many thanks

Comment: How are those rules defined?

Comment: Is Spark the right tool -> what are your options?

Answer (score 0):

> Is Spark the right tool for the job?

I think so.

> the rules are defined in real time and should be applied to the Spark job at real time.

Let's assume the rules are in a database so every batch interval Spark would fetch them and apply one by one. They could also be in a file or any other storage. That's just orthogonal to the main requirement.

> How would I do that?

The batch interval would be *"some time period"*. I *assume* that the payload would have deviceId and temperature. With that you can just use regular filter over temperature and get deviceId back. You don't need stateful pipeline for this unless you want to accumulate data over time that is longer than your batch interval.